# context.getMimeType() returns null and inputStream.available() returns 0 in servlet

Tags: java, database, servlets, download

ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

```
        if (result.next()) {
            // gets file name and file blob data
            String fileName = result.getString("Name");

            Blob blob = result.getBlob(3);

            InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();

            int fileLength = inputStream.available();

      //      out.println("fileLength = " + fileLength);


            ServletContext context = getServletContext();

            // sets MIME type for the file download

            String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);
       //     String mimeType = "image/jpeg";


            if (mimeType == null) {        
                mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
            }
```

I am trying to download data from a database. Im using Oracle. What am i doing wrong here?

context.getMimeType always returns null and inputStream.available() always returns 0.

I looked at other answers but they were not relevant to me. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Its given below :)

I realized that getting the mime was not necessary as i just needed the code to run for image files.

```
 if (result.next()) {
                 // gets file name and file blob data
                String fileID = result.getString("image_id");
                Blob blob = result.getBlob(3);
                InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
                int length = (int)blob.length();
                ServletContext context = getServletContext();

                 // set content properties and header attributes for the response
                response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                response.setContentLength(length);
                String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileID);
                 response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                 // writes the file to the client
                 OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
                 ServletOutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
                 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(output);
                 byte[] arr1 = blob.getBytes(1, length);
                 bos.write(arr1);

                inputStream.close();
                outStream.close();             
        }
```